# Do sample sizes in different groups have to be identical? (major imbalance)

Tags: regression

Suppose there is a study where they want to test if stopping to eat meat vs continuing to eat meat prevents some disease from happening. The study lasts 3 years and they want to compare the rate of developing a particular disease in:

- Group A:  people without the disease who stopped eating meat during the study
- vs Group B: people without the disease that continued to eat meat during the study

Ideally, some regression model (e.g. logistic regression) would be used to measure the impact of different covariates on developing thee  disease in both groups.

Suppose we are in a country where there not many people without the disease that are willing to stop eating meat and it is very difficult to find such people. On the other hand, there are many people who will gladly continue to eat meat. There are many people in the general population without the disease that want to continue eating meat. However, there are not many people in the general population without the disease that do not want to stop eating meat. In short, in the general population, there are far more people in Group A compared to Group B.

The researchers manage to find 1000 people willing to give up meat for the study. The researchers do their best to understand the major characteristics of all these 1000 people that might act as possible confounders. The researchers take note to limit variability within the gender, age, ethnicity, medical history and lifestyles to the best of their ability. For example, these 1000 people are all born and raised in the same country, all males, no major medical diseases as of the date of study and work in similar jobs, similar incomes, etc.

Typically, the researchers would then try to match these 1000 people in Group A to 1000 people in Group B. This is said to make the study more robust and prevent confounding. Each person in Group A will be matched with a similar person from Group B such that both their characteristics are similar as can be.

I was wondering about the following point: Suppose many people from Group B that are willing to participate in the study (far more than 1000) - these people in Group B could contribute valuable information to the development of the disease in meat eaters. However, we do not want to flood the study with people from Group B to shadow the people from Group A. Yet we also do not want to discard valuable information of people from Group B.

Is it possible to have a statistically valid study with 1000 people in Group A and 100,000 people in Group B? That is, is it possible to match one person from Group A with multiple similar people from Group B (i.e. 1:N)? Provided the matching is done correctly - can doing this (i.e. significantly imbalanced group sizes) serve to increase the statistical validity of the study without adding further bias? Or is it better just to have 1:1 for Group A: Group B?